# Summarize table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that I want to pull percentage of total information from.  The table has 5 columns (Date, User, LoadNbr, Approval and Week)

```
Date  User Id  Load Number  approval
4/1/2018  ABC123  111A  Auto
4/1/2018  ABC123  123A  Manual
4/1/2018  DEF456  234A  Auto
4/1/2018  ABC123  122B  Manual
4/1/2018  DEF456  756F  Manual
4/1/2018  ABC123  855F  Auto
4/2/2018  DEF456  684D  Auto
4/2/2018  ABC123  989S  Manual
4/2/2018  ABC123  203T  Manual
4/2/2018  ABC123  300Y  Manual
4/2/2018  DEF456  989Q  Auto
4/3/2018  IJK899  456A  Auto
4/3/2018  IJK899  632J  Manual
4/3/2018  IJK899  258G  Auto
```

I am trying to have a summary table that will populate each time up connect to a new source that would show something like the following;

```
Date      Auto  Manual  Total  Auto%
4/1/2018  3     3       6      50.00%
4/2/2018  2     3       5      40.00%
4/3/2018  2     1       3      66.67%
```

I know this is a remedial question and apologize for my limited abilities.  any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in DAX using `SUMMARIZECOLUMNS` and `ADDCOLUMNS` to create a new summary table:

```
Summary =
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table2[Date],
            "Auto", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2), Table2[Approval] = "Auto"),
            "Manual", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Table2), Table2[Approval] = "Manual")),
        "Total", [Auto] + [Manual],
        "Auto%", DIVIDE([Auto], [Auto] + [Manual]))
```

---

You can also do it in the query editor:

1. Remove the `User Id` column.
2. Pivot on the `approval` column. (Select that column and do Transform > Pivot Column using `Load Number` as the Values Column.)
3. Create a custom column for `Total`. (Add Column > Custom Column and use `= [Auto] + [Manual]` for the formula.)
4. Create a custom column for `Auto%`. (`= [Auto] / [Total]`)